# Hiding Rows with Blank Fields in Access Subreport

Tags: ms-access, filter, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a subreport, ExpenSubrpt, in Access 2010 that’s basically a table with two columns: YearNo, and Amount. These values are taken from another table, Expenditures. Long story short, some records in my database have rows with no YearNo. What I want to do is to hide the rows that don’t have a YearNo, ie. YearNo is blank but there is something in Amount.  For example:

```
YearNo     Amount
             20
  1          50
```

I want the first row to not be visible.  I’ve tried putting

```
"[YearNo] <> " " AND [YearNo] IS NOT NULL"
```

into the Data -> Filter tab, but it gives me a syntax error (missing operator). When I removed the space, the error goes away but it doesn't filter, either. I've also tried calling a query by using the OnLoad event.

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
     DoCmd.OpenQuery "Expenditures Query"
End Sub
```

Query:

```
SELECT Expenditures.YearNo, Expenditures.Amount
FROM Expenditures
WHERE (((Expenditures.YearNo) Is Not Null));
```

However, this doesn't work either. I’m not really sure what to do from here, or if there’s a better way to filter this form. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Base the report on a query. YearNo is likely to be null, it is most unlikely that it will be equal to a space-filled string. [YearNo} > 0 will also exclude nulls.

Comment: How do I base a report on a query?

Comment: Use the report wizard if you are not familiar with MS Access.

Comment: Doing it this way worked.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change your query to have the "Not" before the field name, like this...

```
SELECT Expenditures.YearNo, Expenditures.Amount
FROM Expenditures
WHERE ((Not(Expenditures.YearNo) Is Null));
```

Comment: Not really, for one thing `> 0` excludes nulls. In addition, I think you must mean `Expenditures.YearNo Is Not Null` There is a remote possibility that `Expenditures.YearNo` is a zero-length string, or a space filled string.

Comment: I agree with you Fionnuala. I didn't see your comment when I answered. The sub report should be based on a Query and > 0 will exclude nulls. And I just tried the Query with ((Not(Expenditures.YearNo) Is Null)) and then (((Expenditures.YearNo) IS Not Null)) and both ways worked equally well.

Comment: You will find a time difference if you have a lot of rows. The general rule is to keep all expressions to the right of the field / column name.